# ADMM variants with large number of constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

With a non-differentiable and convex functions $f$ and $g$, I am solving a problem of the form $\arg \min_y f(A - By) + g(y)$ using ADMM. That is, I formulate the problem as
$$\min f(x) + g(y)$$
subject to
$$ x = A - By$$
where $y \in \mathbb{R}^{p}$ is the primal variable, and $x \in \mathbb{R}^m, A\in\mathbb{R}^M, B \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times p}$ with $M \gg p$.

However, in implementing the ADMM algorithm to solve this problem, I am finding that the algorithm is **extremely** slow to converge. I suppose this is not surprising given that a small change in $y$ can have a dramatic effect on many of the constraints $x = A - By$.

I am guessing this is a known problem: I am hoping someone can point my in the direction of work which deals with this issue, or suggest alternative approaches to solving this type of problem.

Comment: Have you spent much time tuning the ADMM step size?

Comment: What are typical values for $p$ and $M$? Can you say what type of application you're doing?

Comment: Why does $\tilde f$ not appear in the reformulated problem? Was the tilde a typo? Also I think the question should state that $x \in \mathbb R^M$.

Comment: Fixed the $\tilde{f}$. Regarding step sizes -- yes, have adjusted but this helps very little. In my application, $p \approx 100$ and $M \approx 15000$.

Comment: Usually tuning the ADMM step size makes a very large difference, in my experience. I'd be curious to see a plot of the objective function value versus the iteration, for 500 iterations (and for a few different values of the step size). Looking at convergence plots like that often helps to diagnose whether or not the algorithm is working correctly.

Comment: Agreed -- the step size tuning is crucial, but for this particular application, the step size modification from the Boyd book are not particularly helpful. I am certain the algorithm is "correct" in the sense that there is no bug or issue with the derivations (all the steps are remarkably simple, and can be double checked with existing solvers).

Comment: In my experience, if the algorithm is converging extremely slowly, there is always a decent chance that there's a bug, even if you've checked everything carefully. Looking at the convergence plots is an important way to diagnose the behavior of the algorithm.

Comment: Which step size modifications are you referring to? If a step size heuristic is failing, it's possible that you need to just try a range of step sizes and see which one works best (which one gives the best convergence plot, that is).

Comment: Just curious why you don't just solve the unconstrained problem directly?

Comment: Consider using an acceleration scheme. C-PALM by Shefi and Teboulle fits your model and has an $O(\frac{1}{n^2})$ convergence rate, which is optimal for first order methods. https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s13675-015-0048-5.pdf

Comment: @iarbel84 Without further assumptions (such as assuming that $f$ is differentiable), OP's problem doesn't have the structure required by C-PALM (and I believe there is no accelerated first-order method that applies to OP's problem without making further assumptions).

Comment: Can you share more information about your functions $f$ and $g$?

Comment: @littleO For Fast C-PALM, neither $f$ nor $g$ need be smooth (they do require that you can explicitly calculate a proximal operator). Only the coupling function imposed on $x=A-By$ needs to be smooth. More generally speaking, if you don't make any assumptions on the problem structure, and have only non-differentiable functions, or if the non-differentiable part is not separable, all you have are subgradient methods which are... slow - $O(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$. You weren't the one asking the question, right? Since I would like to get more info on the problem and functions.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. BOTH f and g are non-differentiable, and both have proximal operators which can be computed efficiently.

Comment: f is something like hinge-loss (but not exactly), and g is a generic regularization term, e.g., the sum of absolute values.

Comment: And one additional detail: B is relatively low rank, which I'm also trying to understand the effect of.

Comment: I'd be curious to see your ADMM iteration written explicitly. If we directly apply ADMM to your reformulated problem (without reformulating the problem further) then the $x$ and $y$ updates are $x^{k+1} = \arg \min_x L(x, y^k, z^k)$ and $y^{k+1} = \arg \min_y L(x^{k+1},y,z^k)$ where $L$ is the augmented Lagrangian $L(x,y,z) = f(x) + g(y) + \langle z, x + By - A \rangle + \frac{\rho}{2} \| x + By - A \|^2$. The $x$-update is easy because it reduces to the prox-operator of $f$. However, the $y$-update does not reduce to the proximal operator of $g$. How do you perform the $y$-update?

Comment: I've used both an existing solver (since its simply a regularized least squares problem), but I have also tried a linearized ADMM where I approximate the y update in a way which only involves evaluating the prox of $g$ (https://www.math.ucla.edu/~wotaoyin/papers/genenarlized_admm_linear_conv.html.). Both exhibit oscillations in a not-that-great neighborhood of the solution when adaptively updating step sizes, and are extremely slow to converge with step sizes fixed.

Comment: Perhaps a tangential comment, but to avoid the difficult $y$-update, one approach is to reformulate your problem as minimizing $F(x,y) + G(x,y)$, where $F(x,y) = f(x) + g(y)$ and $G$ is the indicator function of $\{ (x,y) \mid x + By = A \}$. Then you can minimize $F(x,y) + G(x,y)$ using the Douglas-Rachford method. Evaluating the proximal operator of $F$ reduces to evaluating the proximal operators of $f$ and $g$ (both easy). Computing the proximal operator of $G$ reduces to solving a linear algebra problem (which is not too large in this case because $p \approx 100$).

Comment: When you say "extremely slow to converge with step sizes fixed", how many ADMM iterations are we talking about? Does it eventually converge to a pretty good solution? Would be interesting to see the convergence plots.

Comment: More directly related to your question: it would be interesting to try the version of Chambolle-Pock that uses diagonal preconditioning and see if it makes a difference. http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.381.6056&rep=rep1&type=pdf Chambolle-Pock is quite similar to linearized ADMM, and I've found that this version with diagonal preconditioning can be helpful. It would also be interesting to try the [POGS](https://stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pogs.html) algorithm of Fougner and Boyd, which uses Douglas-Rachford / ADMM with preconditioning.

Comment: By the way, the preconditioning strategy described in the POGS paper sounds complicated, but if you look at what the code does it's something much simpler (at least that was true a few years ago when I looked into it).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111155/discussion-between-user23658-and-littleo).